# Is time spent in the Schengen area on a working visa ignored for the purposes of the 90/180 rule?

Tags: schengen

I am normally subject to the 90/180 rule while in the Schengen area. It looks like I may have an opportunity to work in Austria on a 3-month temporary contract. Obviously that will require a different type of visa. If I go ahead, can I just ignore those 3 months for the purposes of the 90/180 rule? For example, can I spend 90 days in Germany before the contract begins and 90 days in France after it ends?

Comment: Yes. if you have either a D- Visa or a residence permit for thise 3 months in Austria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407

> Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

Note, however, your stay in other Schengen countries do count into the 90/180 rule. In practice enforcing this might be lackadaisical as you can often cross the border without a passport check but it is the law nonetheless.